# Geolocalização pelo segmento da empresa

Tags: google-maps, geolocalização

Bom dia, alguém sabe uma forma de localizar uma empresa pelo segmento dela ?

Exemplo: Quero verificar quais são as empresas que existem em um determinado raio, cujo segmento seja farmacia. Vi isso em um outro software e não sei se ele utilizou a API do google, outra API ou a própria base de dados. Agradeço quem puder ajudar

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa API:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=pt-br

Comment: No atributo "Types" : ""; têm o ramo de atividade.

Comment: Nessa URL você tem os tipo de locais também. 
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types?hl=pt-br
Além disso da pra cruzar dados com outras API do google.

Comment: Muito obrigado @alxwca estava precisando a algum tempo.